# Why does Transform in JavaFX looks like 3D?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

Looks like [`Transform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/transform/Transform.html) class in `JavaFX` contains 3 coordinates (x, y and z).

What will happen if I rotate out of plane? Will it do perspective?

**UPDATE**

Actually object disappears if rotated out of plane even by 1 degree. Why?

```
public class TransformTry extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Drawing Operations Test");
        Group root = new Group();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(300, 250);
        //canvas.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(1, new Point3D(0, 1, 0))); // square disappears
        canvas.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(1, new Point3D(0, 0, 1))); // rotates correctly
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.strokeRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I found a way to use perspective camera, but it works strange: it looks always from above the center of a window, so out-of-plane object changes on window resize:

```
public class ShapeTry01 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {



        Shape shape = new Rectangle(100,100,50,50);
        shape.setStroke(Color.RED);
        shape.setFill(null);

        Group group = new Group();
        group.getChildren().add(shape);
        //group.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(10, new Point3D(0, 0, 1)));
        group.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(10, new Point3D(0, 1, 0)));

        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
        camera.setFieldOfView(45);

        Scene scene = new Scene(group);
        scene.setCamera( camera );

        stage.setTitle("ShapeTry01");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }


}
```

Comment: so I did. now your turn: say something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaFX 2 was started with 3D in mind, thus a lot of API has z coordinate mentioned. But actually useful 3D was added only in JavaFX8 (to be released in next year).

You can see documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/3d_graphics/jfxpub-3d_graphics.htm and try developers preview: https://jdk8.java.net/download.html

Comment: So, currently out of plane transformations just silently kill the drawings?

Comment: unless you attach Perspective Camera to your scene: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/PerspectiveCamera.html

Comment: it is possible even in JavaFX2? Can you hint me where to code camera in sample above please?

Comment: try Ensemble sample, there are few 3d snippets: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2/samples/Ensemble/index.html